# How To redirect to Home Page on cancel button, without entering the hard coded home page url

Tags: visualforce

```
Pagereference CancelButton() ---- Method.
```

Comment: Homepage URL didn't change with org so you can hardcode that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply make:

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/');
pageRef.setRedirect(true);
return pageRef:
```

It's a simple hardcoded value and doesn't change between orgs, so you can safely use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a StandardController or StandardSetController, the convention is to use the `cancel` method.

```
StandardController stdController;
public MyPageController(StandardController ctrl) {
  stdController = ctrl;
}
...
public PageReference cancel() {
  return ctrl.cancel();
}
```